# Autowrite when changing tab in vim

Tags: vim

"autowrite" doesn't seem to work when switching tab in vim.

Is there a way to enable it?

(I could remap 'gt' and 'gT' but I'd like to find a cleaner way).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe use an autocmd to run w on BufWinLeave

Comment: Changing tab doesn't trigger BufWinLeave event. Tabs are in the same window. thx anyway.

Comment: No, tabs are not in the same window, if you speak of Vim windowing management. Maybe, though, changing tab leaves a window active… Use TabLeave or WinLeave instead of BufWinLeave - so `:au TabLeave * w`